# Proper subclassing of SKSpriteNode and instance initialization

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, initialization, subclass, skspritenode

I am trying to subclass SKSpriteNode so that I can use it to create different characters with different properties for a game. I know this should be a trivial task, but I am having a hard time understanding how to initialize a variable when instances are created.
In the header I have:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MyClass : SKSpriteNode 
@property int myVariable;
@end
```

And in the implementation:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
@interface MyClass ()
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myVariable;

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        myVariable = 100;
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I create the node in the scene:

```
@implementation GameScene
{
    MyClass *mySprite;
}

- (void)didMoveToView: (SKView *) view
{
    mySprite = [MyClass spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image.png"];
}
```

The value of myVariable is 0, which I assume it means that spriteNodeWithImageNamed does not execute the init method. If I use:

```
mySprite = [[MyClass alloc] init]; // or mySprite = [MyClass new];
mySprite = [MyClass spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

The variable name is correctly set to 100, but then reverted to 0 by spriteNodeWithImageNamed.

I have also tried:

```
mySprite = [[MyClass alloc] init]; // or mySprite = [MyClass new];
[mySprite setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

In this case the value of myVariable is correct, but no image appears when I add the node to the scene. What init method is called when spriteNodeWithImageNamed is used? Am I improperly overriding the SKSpriteNode init method?

Comment: with modern obj-c and Xcode, no need to `@synthesize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done everything correctly with creating a class, but you need to keep in mind that you are calling the factory method `spriteNodeWithImageNamed`, which then initializes and allocates by itself. Thus, if you want to use your custom `init` method you need to override the factory method as well.

Inside of your implementation of MyClass, override the method to call your initializer:

```
+ (instancetype) spriteNodeWithImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName{
    MyClass *newClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    SKTexture *spriteTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:imageName];
    newClass.size = spriteTexture.size;
    newClass.texture = spriteTexture;
    return newClass;
}
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have questions.

***EDIT**: Im actually a little tempted to ditch this, only because SKSpriteNode doesn't have an `init` method (or at least not that we know of). So unless you want to dive deep into Apple's mysteries then just do it this way:

```
+ (instancetype) spriteNodeWithImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName{
    MyClass *newClass = [[MyClass alloc] initWithImageNamed:imageName];
    newClass.myVariable = 100;
    return newClass;
}
```

You could instead override `initWithImage` to put in myVariable, but the whole point is that I'd avoid trying to use the `init` initializer with SKSpriteNode.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, and the value of myVariable now is correct. However, the node does not appear on the scene. Does it have to do with loading the texture? According to the manual: "Sprite Kit defers loading and preparing the texture as long as possible". 
The texture data is loaded when: The size method on the texture object is called. Another method is called that requires the texture’s size, such as creating a new SKSpriteNode object that uses the texture object. One of the preload methods is called. Since we no longer call the texture from SKSpriteNode that may be the reason?

Comment: Well, you call `[super init]` so you really do have a spriteNode except for the extra variable that you added. The texture should initialize fine. What are you seeing? If it's a red "X" then the image is not there or name is being entered wrong. If you see nothing is probably because the zPosition might not be set, it's in the wrong position/ not added as a child, or simply the whole object is deallocated and it's not there. Try to take a closer look at your code or post in an edit how you handle the node up to the point where you add it as a child and where you expect to see it.

Comment: Thanks again. The node is there, but its size is 0. This is why the sprite is not visible. Although I could make the node appear using an action: [newClass runAction:[SKAction setTexture:texture resize:YES]]; Other things about the node still do not work properly: child nodes I add to it are invisible, and contacts are not detected. I guess there are some factory initializations that are not reproduced when SKSpriteNode is subclassed. It would be interesting to take a look at the factory implementation to have more details about its methods.

Comment: yeah I figured you'd have some problems just using the normal init... check my edit above ^. I just use the spriteNode's initWithImageNamed which should perform the background initializations that you're having problems with.

Comment: Ok, now it works! I guess the init is not required with the initWithImageNamed method. Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Max. Shouldn't the same process work when overriding the spriteNodeWithTexture factory method?:+ (instancetype) spriteNodeWithTexture:(SKTexture *)texture{
    MyClass *newClass =[[MyClass alloc] spriteNodeWithTexture:texture]; return newClass;
} No matter what I do, it continues to complain: "No visible interface for 'MyClass' declares the selector 'spriteNodeWithTexture'". I am not sure why it would look for an interface declaration in class method.

Comment: its not working because look at the initialization call here. when you call `[MyClass alloc]` you allocate an instance of MyClass. Then, you attempt to call the spriteNodeWithTexture method that you are currently overriding... instead call `initWithTexture:`. so put in `[[MyClass alloc] initWithTexture:texture];` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it. Create your own custom init method, and simply call the default spritenode initWithImage.

```
-(id)initShipWithType:(ShipType)type {
    self = [super initWithImageNamed:[self getShipSprite:type]];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```